# Html 5 video does not auto play

Tags: html, video, autoplay

The video does not autoplay, tried it in Chrome 28 and Firefox 23. Also tried just plain `autoplay` and `autoplay="true"`

```
<video id="video_background"  autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted"
volume="0"><source src="video/background/MH.webm" type="video/webm"> <source
src="video/background/MHB.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="video/background/MH.ogv"
type="video/ogg">Video not supported </video>
```

Update: Thanks for your help. When I take jquery out the video starts to autoplay. Any ideas?

Update: Looks like it was a issue with jquery mobile which was on the page for some reason. When I take out jquery mobile and add back in regularly jquery it works fine Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Does play for me http://jsfiddle.net/XhSUN/

Comment: I have no problem either in Chrome28 on OSX - silly question, but have you looking in network tools to make sure that the path to the video is okay and it's being served correctly?

Comment: make sure your source path is correct.

Comment: Yah checked that the video does play fine when I right click and say play. Must be something else in the rest of the code.

Comment: share the code you think having issue..

Comment: When I take jquery out the video starts to autoplay. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you serve the page and video online, or from your local file system? Does make a difference with permission sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery-mobile from Google's hosted libraries?

I had the same issue and autoplay worked when I replaced the jquery-mobile link for an actual file.

Hope that helps!